# Using bash delete line if line below match does not exist

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have output from an HP Online Administrator that shows blade bay numbers and some other information. I would like to delete lines that contain no bay data. Below is my example file:

```
Bay 1
enc01(111.11.111.1) - Server Name: hostname1.example.com
MGMT IP Address: 192.168.0.1
Bay 2
enc01(111.11.111.1) - Server Name: hostname2.example.com
MGMT IP Address: 192.168.0.2
Bay 3
enc01(111.11.111.1) - Server Name: hostname3.example.com
MGMT IP Address: 192.168.0.3
Bay 4
enc01(111.11.111.1) - Server Name: hostname4.example.com
MGMT IP Address: 192.168.0.4
Bay 5
Bay 6
Bay 7
enc01(111.11.111.1) - Server Name: hostname7.example.com
MGMT IP Address: 192.168.0.7
Bay 8
enc01(111.11.111.1) - Server Name: hostname8.example.com
MGMT IP Address: 192.168.0.8
Bay 9
enc01(111.11.111.1) - Server Name: hostname9.example.com
MGMT IP Address: 192.168.0.9
Bay 10
Bay 11
enc01(111.11.111.1) - Server Name: hostname11.example.com
MGMT IP Address: 192.168.0.11
Bay 12
Bay 13
Bay 14
Bay 15
Bay 16
```

I would like to remove all the Bay lines where the enc01(111.11.111.1) line is not directly below. So, I would like to delete:

```
Bay 5
Bay 6
Bay 10
Bay 12
Bay 13
Bay 14
Bay 15
Bay 16
```

From the listing because below those bays, there is no blades to list. These are compleatly random and some enclosures will have more empty bays that others, so it has to be dynamic.

I would like to use sed if possible. I am also using Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.6.

Thanks!
Joe

Comment: `grep -v '^Bay \d\d*'` … `sed '/^Bay \d\d*/d'` … Why would you _like to use sed, if possible_?

Comment: You forgot to post your code. StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all.  `awk` would be a useful tool for the project. Search here for `[awk] prev` and you may find some useful ideas. Good luck.

Comment: @kojiro Which grep and sed support `\d`? Mine don't, it seems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk` you can do:

```
awk '/enc01\(111\.11\.111\.1\)/{print p; print} /^Bay/{p=$0}' file
Bay 1
enc01(111.11.111.1) - Server Name: hostname1.example.com
Bay 2
enc01(111.11.111.1) - Server Name: hostname2.example.com
Bay 3
enc01(111.11.111.1) - Server Name: hostname3.example.com
Bay 4
enc01(111.11.111.1) - Server Name: hostname4.example.com
Bay 7
enc01(111.11.111.1) - Server Name: hostname7.example.com
Bay 8
enc01(111.11.111.1) - Server Name: hostname8.example.com
Bay 9
enc01(111.11.111.1) - Server Name: hostname9.example.com
Bay 11
enc01(111.11.111.1) - Server Name: hostname11.example.com
```

Comment: darn, I keep forgetting that S.O. **is** a free coding service ;-) ! Good luck to all.

Comment: I get your point. I think I shouldn't have answered without seeing OP's attempt.

Comment: Hey guys! Thanks for the help with this.

I have tried several things, but none of it was working. I didnt think I should post my failures and I really had no idea how to do it... But...

Here is what I tried:cat AddressReport-enc01 |egrep -v 'Bay [0-9]{1,}/\renc.*'

I was trying to grep the carriage return \r if enc was not there. That didnt work though...

Let me try this and see how it goes... 

Thanks again!
Joe

Answer (score 0):

Though I would prefer **@anubhava** answer, using GNU `grep` you can execute this:

```
grep -A1 -B1 'enc01(111\.11\.111\.1)' input_file
```

Please notice that it will place a line containing a group separator (--) between contiguous groups of matches.